# How to enable web services in moodle?

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile, moodle-theme

i have developed a plugin and when i install it i want to enable web services automatically while installing, i don't want to manually enable it at => **site administration > server > overview > enable web services**. I can add some plugins i.e. attendance plugin as dependencies for my plugin so the user is asked to install them while installing my plugin i.e in version.php

```
$plugin->dependencies = ['mod_attendance' => ANY_VERSION, 'webservice_restful' => ANY_VERSION];
```

, is there something similar i can do to prompt user to enable **web services** and **RESTful protocols** etc.

Thank you.

Comment: I would say automatically enabling web services is a very bad idea, it would open up a security hole

Comment: @RussellEngland i don't want to automatically enable web services, the user will be prompted for it, and only after he accepts will i enable web services